# Problems with GridView and HyperLinkColumn

Tags: asp.net

When using control DataGrid, I can perfectly use this type of column:

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="url_doc" DataTextField="des_doc" HeaderText="Document">
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
</asp:HyperLinkColumn>
```

Where "url_doc" come from stored procedure with this value:

```
selet   '../Documentos/'
                  || res.cod_op
                  || '/'
                  || tdo.des_tipo_doc
                  || '/'
                  || '01'
                  || '/'
                  || res.file_name as URL_DOC
from MyTable
```

URL_DOC stores path of a document file, which is included in a sub folder of my asp.net project. When I click on HyperLinkColumn, I can open that document file.

Now, if I try to use GridView, I can't find any column as good as HyperLinkColumn. When using GridView, I tried to use HyperLinkField like:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField
                    DataNavigateUrlFields="url_doc"
                    DataTextField="des_doc" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="url_doc"  />
```

However, when I click on HyperLinkField, program tries to open a file named "url_doc", not the path included in the variable url_doc.

Any idea how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The DataNavigateUrlFormatString property gives you a way to format a url if the only data you have is an Id like this "~\details.aspx?ProductID={0}". If you leave this empty it will print the valur you bind to the DataNavigateUrlFields property instead. Take a look at this link for  more help [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx).